# Advance tab position in C++?

Tags: c++, formatting

I'm currently writing a program that has debug output strewn throughout it. This is all well and good, but I'd like to be able to advance the tab position for things in different scopes, for instance, this is what I have right now:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
printf("Updating player\n");
#endif
player.Update();
#ifndef NDEBUG
printf("Done updating player\n");
#endif
```

I'd like to have so that all the output called between these two blocks is advanced by one tab position; however, simply adding tabs to the beginning of Player::Update() output is incredibly clunky AND difficult to maintain.

Anybody got any help? (Note: I have no problem with using cout instead; I was just recently lectured about the overhead and insecurity with cout)

Comment: Overhead and insecurity of `cout`? Perhaps you should lecture us too! `cout` is perhaps more secure, in that you can't get format flags wrong, and any overhead is typically minimal. (Esp. if you're outputting to a file, or even a screen...)

Comment: I'm personally not in favour of it, but a collaborator on the project changed couts to printfs, due to (pasted from http://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#ll_iostream):
"# The time to run the static c'tors impacts startup time of applications—a critical time for GUI apps.
# The static c'tors cause the app to pull many extra pages of memory off the disk: both the code for the static c'tors in each .o file and the small amount of data that gets touched."

Comment: @Thanatos this isn't a secret. The C++ IO streams are virtually impossible to be as fast as the C IO library. I'm talking both about run time and compile time. And the differences between the C and C++ IO libraries have nothing to do with security.

Comment: @wilhelm: iostream, at least as implemented by GNU (which leaves a lot of optimizations on the table) is indeed horrible at runtime, but @Robot is referring to *initialization* time. It's easy to verify that iostreams takes negligible static ctor, initialization time by timing Hello World. This is one example of the LLVM project's STL Wasn't Invented Here syndrome.

Comment: @wilhelmtell:  The difference in type safety could be described as a difference in security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a class that essentially maintained a "tab count" and had a `print_line` function: when called, it would output tab-count tabs, and then print the line. While you could have a `increment_indent` function, you could create a sister object `TabIndent` using RAII: When it is created, increment the tab, when it is destructed, decrement the indent:

```
some_function()
{
    TabIndent ti(global_debug_outputter);

    global_debug_outputted.print_line("foo bar baz");
    // ti's d-tor calls global_debug_outputted.unindent()
}

class TabIndent
{
public:
    TabIndent(Outputter &o) : m_outputter(o)
    {
        o.indent();
    }
    ~TabIndent()
    {
        o.unindent();
    }
};

class Outputter
{
// functions indent, unindent, print_line...
};
```

Good use of `inline`s will let the compiler optimize them out when their bodies are empty. Use `#ifndef` in the `Outputter` class, and let the compiler optimize the rest out.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using printf directly, create a class to handle console output and have a member function such as `SetTabLevel()` -- and perhaps also `IncrementTabLevel()` and `DecrementTabLevel()` -- which tells the class how many tabs to add at the beginning of each subsequent line.

Comment: Bonus point: use RAII to manage the tab level, such that `IncrementTabLevel` returns an object which upon destruction will call `DecrementTabLevel` automagically. This way you won't forget ;)

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that C++ iostreams are very customizable. The bad news is that the interface is a bit weird.

```
#include <iostream>

class scoped_streambuf : public std::streambuf {
    std::streambuf *sb;
    size_t tabs;
    bool at_nl;

    virtual int_type overflow( int_type c = traits_type::eof() ) {
        if ( at_nl ) for ( size_t t = 0; t < tabs; ++ t ) {
            int_type r = sb->sputc( '\t' );
            if ( r == traits_type::eof() ) return r;
        }
        int_type r = sb->sputc( c );
        if ( r == traits_type::eof() ) return r;
        at_nl = c == '\n';
        return c;
    }

    virtual int sync() { return sb->pubsync(); }

    static void uninstall( std::ios_base::event what, std::ios_base &ios, int ) {
        if ( what != std::ios_base::erase_event ) return;

        std::ostream &os = dynamic_cast< std::ostream & >( ios );
        scoped_streambuf *this_ = static_cast< scoped_streambuf * >( os.rdbuf() );
        os.rdbuf( this_->sb );
        delete this_;
    }

public:
    scoped_streambuf( std::ostream &inos )
        : sb( inos.rdbuf( this ) ), tabs(), at_nl() {
        inos.register_callback( &uninstall, 0 );
    }

    friend std::ostream &indent( std::ostream &os ) {
        ++ dynamic_cast< scoped_streambuf & >( * os.rdbuf() ).tabs;
        return os;
    }

    friend std::ostream &outdent( std::ostream &os ) {
        -- dynamic_cast< scoped_streambuf & >( * os.rdbuf() ).tabs;
        return os;
    }
};
std::ostream &indent( std::ostream & );
std::ostream &outdent( std::ostream & );

struct indent_scope {
    std::ostream &os;
    indent_scope( std::ostream &inos ) : os( inos ) { os << indent; }
    ~indent_scope() { os << outdent; }
};

int main() {
    new scoped_streambuf( std::cout );

    std::cout << "hello\n";
    {
        indent_scope s( std::cout );
        std::cout << "world" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "!\n";
}
```

I checked that the `scoped_streambuf` indeed deletes itself when the associated stream is destroyed, but apparently `std::cout` itself is never destroyed on GCC.

Level-up iostream fu, whee!